# Does every equation involving $+,-,\times,\div,\sqrt{},\mathbb Q$ only have solutions in the algebraic numbers

Tags: number-theory, field-theory

Let's say you have an equation $f(x)=0$ where $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is composed of $$+,-,\times,\div,\sqrt{},n \in \mathbb Z$$
If $f$ has only finitely many solutions, are all the solutions algebraic?

I've tried (structural) induction. The cases $n$, $\div$ and $\times$ are easy. $+$ and $-$ are not.

I've been trying to reduce it to a polynomial equation. Problem is that doing $\sqrt{A}=B \implies A=B^2$ makes the RHS more complicated. If the RHS contains sums of square roots then this doesn't make progress. (Maybe I could do more work here?)

I don't see how to use the fact the algebraic numbers are closed under the above operations.

I've been trying to think of a counterexample.

Comment: Finitely many solutions where?  In $\mathbb{C}$?  In $\mathbb{R}$?  (Also, what do you mean by $\sqrt{}$ exactly?)

Comment: @EricWofsey Does it make a big difference? By $\sqrt{}$, I mean the function that maps $x$ to $\sqrt{x}^+$ (positive square root)?

Comment: @EricWofsey Because of the discussion on the square root, I'll say $\mathbb R$

Comment: You can remove all square roots by replacing the single equation by a system of polynomial equations in several variables.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_polynomial_equations#Examples_and_extensions - The last paragraph here suggests the answer to my question is yes

Comment: Indeed. Once you have a polynomial system, groebner bases let you construct an equivalent system in triangular form. Using that what you want should follow.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Is there an elementary proof of the fact that a polynomial system can always be expressed in triangular form? I think I can sketch out a proof that the algebraic numbers are closed under the field operations, using field extensions and minimal polynomials of matrices, if that makes sense. Not sure if it's "elementary" for other people.

Comment: That algebraical numbers are closed under the field operations is proved in essentially every textbook that treats fields, and is quite easy. That you can triangularize polynomial systems is not very hard but you do need groebner bases or something equivalent. The book by Cox on *Varieties, ideals and algorithms* is a great exposition of the theory.

Comment: Are the formulas also finitely many operations? Because if not I think you can generate $e$.

Comment: @Joffan Finitely many operations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any radical expression exists in a tower of radical extensions of $\Bbb Q(x)$. For instance, consider

$$ T(x)=\sqrt{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x-1}}+\sqrt{x}-3.$$

Then $T$ exists in the top of the tower of radical extensions

$$ \begin{array}{c} \Bbb Q\left(\sqrt{x+1},\sqrt{x},\sqrt{x-1},\sqrt{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x-1}}\right) \\ | \\ \Bbb Q(\sqrt{x+1},\sqrt{x},\sqrt{x-1}) \\ | \\ \vdots \\ | \\ \Bbb Q(x) \end{array} $$

where $\Bbb Q(x)$ is the field of rational functions in $x$. Thus, $T$ is algebraic over $\Bbb Q(x)$, so it has a minimal polynomial, which in this case must have degree $\le 16$ since that's the degree of the extension up top. So $T$ is a root of an irreducible polynomial

$$ c_{16}(x)T^{16}+\cdots+c_1(x)T+c_0(x) \tag{$\ast$} $$

where all the $c_i$s are in $\Bbb Q[x]$ (by clearing denominators if necessary; the polynomial in $T$ needn't be monic), and $c_0(x)$ is not the zero polynomial in $x$ since the above polynomial in $T$ is irreducible. If $x$ is a root of the radical equation $T(x)=0$, then plugging it into $(\ast)$ yields $c_0(x)=0$, making $x$ the root of a polynomial equation - algebraic.

Comment: The ingredients of this answer are: 1) You start off with the field $\mathbb Q(x)$ 2) You form a polynomial ring over it $\mathbb Q(x)[u]$ 3) You quotient by an irreducible polynomial in $u$ to get e.g. $\mathbb Q[x][u]/(u^2-x)$ 4) You repeat the preceding two steps, each time doubling the dimensionality of the resulting field relative to $\mathbb Q(x)$ 5) You express $T(x)$ (as in your answer) in the resulting field 6) You interpret multiplication by $T(x)$ to be a linear operator on a vector space of $\mathbb Q(x)$...

Comment: ... 7) You apply the Cayley-Hamilton theorem to get out a minimal polynomial $P$ of $T(x)$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Q(x)$; this polynomial satisfies $P(T(x))=0$ 8) You consider a $k$ for which $T(k)=0$ 9) You substitute $k$ into both sides of the equation $P(T(x)) = 0$ to get $P(T(k))=0 \implies c_0(k)=0$. Hence $k$ is algebraic

Comment: It's a good answer. I think I understood it. Thank you. (I don't know why I wrote out any of the above)

Answer (score 0):

The set of algebraic numbers is *algebraically closed*.  This seems to be the result you are referring to.   Here's a link: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number#Properties

Algebraic closure, together with the fact that $\sqrt a$ is algebraic for $a\in \mathbb Z$ (consider $x^2-a$), should suffice to show that combinations of doing the four arithmetic operations plus $x\rightarrow \sqrt x$ to rational  numbers results in an algebraic number...

It's not clear that you can replace $Q$ with $\bar {\mathbb Q}$,the set of algebraic numbers, here...

Comment: I guess I should add something about $n$-th roots...

Comment: @jkabrg So, $\sqrt3- {\sqrt 2}$...  etc?...

Comment: Ok.  I'll give it a shot...

Comment: "should suffice"? How does it suffice? I honestly do not know what you mean.

Comment: (you seem to be thinking that the problem is to show that any number constructed using the field operations and square roots from integers is algebraic, but it is not that)

Comment: I.e. sums, products, quotient , differences and square roots... I start with an _algebraic_ number...

Comment: Sorry,  I start with a _rational_ number...

Comment: Just in case you're curious:  $x = \sqrt{\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2}} \Rightarrow x^2 = \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2} \Rightarrow x^4 = 1 - 2 \sqrt{6} \Rightarrow (x^4 - 1)^2 = 24$

Comment: I agree with Mariano that it seems you misunderstood the question.